# Running actor manually?

Tags: scala, playframework, akka, jobs, playframework-2.3

I'm working on my first Play Framework 2 application. I want to call a web service every once in a while and store data in the database so I've started writing an actor that is scheduled to every hour. 
Problem is, I'm wasting a lot of time simply waiting for the job to be triggered (even if I've scheduled to be ran every minute while I'm testing. I'd love to be able to start the import manually, simply to make sure it works.

I've tried using the scala console, but it doesn't automatically reload my code every time I save so I have to restart the console manually. I've considered wrapping the import process in a class and use unit testing and mocking but I'm looking for a quicker way, especially because I'm new to Play and Scala.

Any idea or suggestion?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

How about writing a custom sbt task?
A simple way to write an sbt task that loads your application class path, so you can implement the behavior with a method call in your application code, can be found at [sbt-tasks](http://yobriefca.se/sbt-tasks/).

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are using the Akka scheduler inside the Actor to trigger a message to itself which then invokes web service. You can just send *same* message (`ActorRef ! Message`) to the actor while you are doing your testing.